# Unique id/class increment to show different Input using Jquery

Tags: php, jquery, html

I've got a form which currently works as a single line allowing different input fields based on the Production drop down.

i.e. If you choose CPE or CPM you get the inputs for Impressions and Targeting. If you choose *Eggs2Go* then you only get Impressions.

While this works so far, if I add a line and use the drop down menu it affects the first ID tag changing that line and not the new lines options.

```
function showTargetCheck(that) {
        if (that.value == "CPM" || that.value == "CPE" || that.value == "SWIFT") {
            document.getElementById("showTarget").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("showImpressions").style.display = "none";
        }

        else if (that.value == "EGGS") {
            document.getElementById("showImpressions").style.display = "block";
            document.getElementById("showTarget").style.display = "none";
        }

        else {
            document.getElementById("showTarget").style.display = "none";
            document.getElementById("showImpressions").style.display = "none";
        }
    }
```

Is there a way I can give an auto increment to each new line so that the showTarget and ShowImpressions act individually?

Details in the [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/16godohe/7/)

Comment: horrible hybrid mix of jQuery and inline code and native methods. Stick to one or the other and be consistent

Comment: old story of if you don't have time to do it right the first time...why would you have time to do it over again a second time

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't repeat ID's in a page, they must be unique by definition.

The common approach to repeating rows like this is to use common classes for like elements and isolate instances within your event handlers by looking up to parent row element and then looking inside that specific row for needed elements

Assume we change all the repeating ID's to same class name you would then do something like the following in jQuery

```
$('#tableContainer').on('change', 'select', function(e){
  // get row instance starting from `this` 
  var $row = $(this).closest('.tableRow'),
      currVal = $(this).val(),
      // flags for toggling various classes 
      showImpressions = false,
      showTarget = false;

   if (currVal  == "CPM" || currVal  == "CPE" || currVal  == "SWIFT") {
      showTarget = true;
   }
   // other conditionals to set flags based on other values

   // now toggle display of instances of classes within row instance   
   $row.find('.showTarget').toggle(showTarget);
   $row.find('.showImpressions').toggle(showImpressions);

});
```

Comment: Excellent - thank you. I see where I was messing up. I was trying to add incremental values next to id's to make them all unique and should've went a class the entire time. Appreciate your help for this.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned by charlietfl, ids are unique.
Using your existing coding format

Change all id to class

Find the second parentNodes of your select tag

Once the main parentNode is Found, find your siblings input boxes that you need to change

Snippet below

```js
/*
 New IO Line
*/
$('#addNewIOLine').click(function() {
  $('#IOLine').append(
    '<div class="tableRow">' +

    '<div class="tableLeft">' +
    '<input type="date"  name="startDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="date">' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<input type="date"  name="endDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="date">' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<select name="products" onchange="showTargetCheck(this);">' +
    '<option>Select one</option>' +
    '<option disabled>---</option>' +
    '<option value="PRODUCTION">Production</option>' +
    '<option value="CPE">CPE</option>' +
    '<option value="CPM">CPM</option>' +
    '<option value="SWIFT">Swift</option>' +
    '<option value="EGGS">Eggs2Go</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="showImpressions" style="display: none;">' +
    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<input type="number" placeholder="1000" class="imps">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="showTarget" style="display: none;">' +
    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Targeting">' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<input type="number" placeholder="1000" class="imps">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<span class="input-symbol-dollar">' +
    '<input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0.01" class="rates">' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<span class="input-symbol-dollar">' +
    '<input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0.01" class="grosscost">' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<span class="input-symbol-dollar">' +
    '<input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0.01" class="netcost">' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="tableRight">' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Notes" class="notes">' +
    '</div>' +

    '</div>');
});
```

```css
#tableContainer {
  display: table;
}

.tableRow {
  display: table-row;
}

.tableLeft,
.tableRight,
.tableMiddle {
  display: table-cell;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
  function showTargetCheck(that) {
    if (that.value == "CPM" || that.value == "CPE" || that.value == "SWIFT") {
      that.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("showTarget")[0].style.display = "block";
      that.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("showImpressions")[0].style.display = "none";
    } else if (that.value == "EGGS") {
      that.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("showImpressions")[0].style.display = "block";
      that.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("showTarget")[0].style.display = "none";
    } else {
      that.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("showTarget")[0].style.display = "none";
      that.parentNode.parentNode.getElementsByClassName("showImpressions")[0].style.display = "none";
    }
  }
</script>

<!-- IO Table -->
<div id="tableContainer">

  <!-- IO Row -->
  <div class="tableRow">

    <!-- Start Date -->
    <div class="tableLeft">
      <h4>Start</h4>
      <input type="date" name="startDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="date">
    </div>

    <div class="tableMiddle">
      <h4>End</h4>
      <input type="date" name="endDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="date">
    </div>
    <!-- End Date -->

    <!-- Products -->
    <div class="tableMiddle">
      <h4>Products</h4>
      <select name="products" onchange="showTargetCheck(this);">
                <option>Select one</option>
                <option disabled>---</option>
                <option value="PRODUCTION">Production</option>
                <option value="CPE">CPE</option>
                <option value="CPM">CPM</option>
                <option value="SWIFT">Swift</option>
                <option value="EGGS">Eggs2Go</option>
              </select>
    </div>
    <!-- Products -->

    <!-- Show Impressions Only -->
    <div class="showImpressions" style="display: none;">
      <div class="tableMiddle">
        <h4>Impressions</h4>
        <input type="number" placeholder="1000" class="imps">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Show Impressions Only -->

    <!-- Show Targeting & Impressions -->
    <div class="showTarget" style="display: none;">
      <div class="tableMiddle">
        <h4>Targeting</h4>
        <input type="text" placeholder="Targeting">
      </div>

      <div class="tableMiddle">
        <h4>Impressions</h4>
        <input type="number" placeholder="1000" class="imps">
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- Show Targeting & Impressions -->

    <!-- Rates -->
    <div class="tableMiddle">
      <h4>Rate</h4>
      <span class="input-symbol-dollar">
              <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0.01" class="rates">
              </span>
    </div>
    <!-- Rates -->

    <!-- Gross Cost -->
    <div class="tableMiddle">
      <h4>Gross</h4>
      <span class="input-symbol-dollar">
              <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0.01" class="grosscost">
              </span>
    </div>
    <!-- Gross Cost -->

    <!-- Net Cost -->
    <div class="tableMiddle">
      <h4>Net</h4>
      <span class="input-symbol-dollar">
              <input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0.01" class="netcost">
              </span>
    </div>
    <!-- Net Cost -->

    <!-- Notes -->
    <div class="tableRight">
      <h4>Notes</h4>
      <input type="text" placeholder="Notes" class="notes">
    </div>
    <!-- Notes -->

  </div>
  <!-- IO Row -->

</div>

<!-- ADD NEW IO LINE -->
<div id="IOLine"></div>
<button type="button" id="addNewIOLine">+ Add New Line</button>
<!-- ADD NEW IO LINE -->
```

Comment: Thanks for your help with this :)

Comment: Glad to help :D

Answer (score 0):

*(Posted on behalf of the OP)*.

Working version here if anyone needs the reference:

```
/*
    Toggle Impressions and Targeting Fields
    */

$('#tableContainer').on('change', 'select', function(e) {
  // get row instance starting from `this` 
  var $row = $(this).closest('.tableRow'),
    currVal = $(this).val(),
    showImpressions = true,
    showTarget = true,
    showDefault = true;

  if (currVal == "CPM" || currVal == "CPE" || currVal == "SWIFT") {
    showTarget = true;
    showImpressions = false;
    showDefault = false;
  } else if (currVal == "EGGS") {
    showImpressions = true;
    showTarget = false;
    showDefault = false;
  } else if (currVal == "DEFAULT" || currVal == "") {
    showDefault = true;
    showTarget = false;
    showImpressions = false;
  }

  // other conditionals to set flags

  // now toggle instances of classes within row    
  $row.find('.showTarget').toggle(showTarget);
  $row.find('.showImpressions').toggle(showImpressions);
  $row.find('.showDefault').toggle(showDefault);
});

/*
    New IO Line
*/
$('#addNewIOLine').click(function() {
  $('#IOLine').append(
    '<div class="tableRow">' +

    /* DATES */
    '<div class="tableLeft">' +
    '<input type="date"  name="startDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="date">' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<input type="date"  name="endDate" placeholder="MM/DD/YYYY" class="date">' +
    '</div>' +

    /* PRODUCTS */
    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<select name="products">' +
    '<option value="DEFAULT">Production</option>' +
    '<option value="CPE">CPE</option>' +
    '<option value="CPM">CPM</option>' +
    '<option value="SWIFT">Swift</option>' +
    '<option value="EGGS">Eggs2Go</option>' +
    '</select>' +
    '</div>' +

    /* Show Default */
    '<div class="showDefault">' +
    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="N/A" disabled>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<input type="number" placeholder="N/A" class="imps" disabled>' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +

    /* Show Impressions Only */
    '<div class="showImpressions">' +
    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="N/A" disabled>' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<input type="number" placeholder="1000" class="imps">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +

    /* Show Targeting & Impressions */
    '<div class="showTarget">' +
    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Targeting">' +
    '</div>' +

    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<input type="number" placeholder="1000" class="imps">' +
    '</div>' +
    '</div>' +

    /* RATES */
    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<span class="input-symbol-dollar">' +
    '<input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0.01" class="rates">' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +


    /* GROSS COST */
    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<span class="input-symbol-dollar">' +
    '<input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0.01" class="grosscost">' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +


    /* NET COST */
    '<div class="tableMiddle">' +
    '<span class="input-symbol-dollar">' +
    '<input type="number" placeholder="0.00" min="0.01" class="netcost">' +
    '</span>' +
    '</div>' +

    /* NOTES */
    '<div class="tableRight">' +
    '<input type="text" placeholder="Notes" class="notes">' +
    '</div>' +

    '</div>');
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/16godohe/9/.